# Как сделать навигационное меню

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

У меня тут проблема, учусь верстать сайты и решил попробовать сверстать сайт с PSD макета, зашел в тупик когда еще делал логотип, но вродь справился, теперь у меня другая проблема - не могу понять как сделать навигационное меню. Может кто-нибудь поможет, приложу фоточку и код[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

````
```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
    family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <title>Axit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="header-top">
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <h1>AX<span class="letters-IT">IT</span></h1>
                    </div>
                
                    <nav class="main-navigation">
                        <ul class="navigation">
                            <li class="nav-element">
                                <a class="nav-btn" href="#">Features</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-element">
                                <a class="nav-btn" href="#">About</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-element">
                                <a class="nav-btn" href="#">Pricing</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-element">
                                <a class="nav-btn" href="#">Reviews</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-element">
                                <a class="nav-btn" href="#">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
````

````
    css-```body{
        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        display: flex;
    }
    
    ul{
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    header{
        width: 100vw;
    }
    
    #header-top{
        background-color: #000;
    
        width: 100vw;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 70px;
    
        display: flex;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .container{
        margin: 0 10%;
        display: flex;
        
        width: 100vw;
    }
    
    .logo{
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        font-weight: 650;
    
        height: auto;
        align-self: center;
    }
    
    .logo h1{
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .letters-IT{
        color: #f98c3e;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    
    .main-navigation{
        display: flex;
        width: auto;
    }
    
    .navigation{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: inline-flex;
    }
    
    .nav-element{
        align-self: center;
        padding: 0 2%;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    .nav-btn{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
````

Comment: И как обычно чтереотип что сделать меню с помощью списка это круто ... ＞︿＜

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так что-ли?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: consolas;
}

#header-top {
  background-color: #000;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 24px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  color: #FFF;
}

.letters-IT {
  color: #FF6600;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #C0C0C0;
  padding: 24px 18px;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="header-top">
    <div class="container">
      
      <div class="logo">
        <h1>AX<span class="letters-IT">IT</span></h1>
      </div>

      <nav class="main-navigation">
        <ul class="navigation">
          <li class="nav-element">
            <a class="nav-btn" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-element">
            <a class="nav-btn" href="#">About</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-element">
            <a class="nav-btn" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-element">
            <a class="nav-btn" href="#">Reviews</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-element">
            <a class="nav-btn" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```